# Проблема с OpenGL

Tags: g++, ubuntu, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте, решил немного разобраться с OpenGL. Но возникла небольшая проблема, у меня ubuntu, компилятор g++
Вот что говорит компилятор при запуске проекта:

```
main.cpp:2:21: фатальная ошибка: GL\glut.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Библиотеку GL установил:

```
apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev^C
```

Но всё равно, компилятор не видит библиотеку

Comment: Не видит -- это как? Вы ему говорите: "Взять!", а он -- "А где?"

        gcc test.c -o test -lGL -lglut

Answer (score 3):

glut это как бы отдельная библиотека которая дополняет сам GL.

[Скачать можно тут...](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php)